# Name Phone Data sorting from row to columns using Macro in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

i want to split my data and arranged in columns of name address city state n phone but the name is not joining all data in same row, can you pls help me to fix it?
following is the macro codes
thanks

```
Sub ExtractDataFromTextFile()
  Dim strFilename, strTextLine, tState, tZip, tCity, tAddress, tCityState  As String
  Dim iFile, iRow, ChkName, ChkAddress, ChkPhone As Integer
  Dim SplitAddress, TempAddressSplit As Variant
'ChkScrapLine1, ChkScrapLine2, ChkScrapLine3, ChkScrapLine4, ChkScrapLine5, ChkScrapLine6, ChkScrapLine7, ChkScrapLine8, ChkScrapLine9, ChkScrapLine10

  'text file path
  strFilename = "C:\Users\Wasim\Desktop\N.txt"

  'Set how many rows you want to leave on top of data
  iRow = 1

  iFile = FreeFile
  Open strFilename For Input As #iFile

  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine

    strTextLine = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(strTextLine)
    strTextLine = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(strTextLine)


    If Len(strTextLine) > 1 Then

        ChkScrapLine1 = InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "confirm")
        ChkScrapLine2 = InStr(UCase(strTextLine), "SPONSORED")
        ChkScrapLine3 = InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "more")
        ChkScrapLine4 = InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "background")
        ChkScrapLine5 = InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "find")
        ChkScrapLine6 = InStr(UCase(strTextLine), "TRY")
        ChkScrapLine7 = InStr(UCase(strTextLine), "get")
        ChkScrapLine8 = InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "listing")
        ChkScrapLine9 = InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "search")
        If ChkScrapLine1 = 0 And ChkScrapLine2 = 0 And ChkScrapLine3 = 0 And ChkScrapLine4 = 0 And ChkScrapLine5 = 0 And ChkScrapLine6 = 0 And ChkScrapLine7 = 0 And ChkScrapLine8 = 0 And ChkScrapLine9 = 0 Then
            ChkAddress = InStr(strTextLine, ",")
            ChkPhone = InStr(strTextLine, "(")
            If ChkAddress > 0 Then
strTextLine = Replace(strTextLine, ", ", ",")
                SplitAddress = Split(strTextLine, ",")
                tAddress = SplitAddress(0)
                tCity = SplitAddress(1)

                Cells(iRow, 3).Value = strTextLine

            ElseIf ChkPhone > 0 Then
                Cells(iRow, 4).Value = strTextLine
            Else
                iRow = iRow + 1
                Cells(iRow, 1).Value = strTextLine
            End If

        End If
    End If
  Loop
  Close #iFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Can we see what the data looks like?